# including XML declaration in BaseX export called over REST

Tags: database, rest, xquery, basex, xml-declaration

I have been using BaseX and REST for a few months now to play around with some XML files. Up to this point I have been exporting my files using the query:

```
db:export(',char(39),dbName,char(39),',',char(34),'path',char(34),')
```

If this is confusing, it is just because I am showing how it is constructed, the actual call looks like:

```
http://localhost:8984/rest?query=db%3Aexport%28%27dbName%27%2C%22C%3A%5CUsers%5Cdak52%5CDocuments%5Cfolder%22%29
```

Anyways, this works just fine, but I want to include the XML declaration in my output. I have tried setting the `omit-xml-declaration` option to "no" but I guess I am not doing it correctly. It works fine when I try to export from the BaseX GUI specifying that option, but I want to do it all via REST, and that is where I am having problems. Below is my query with the option included.

```
http://localhost:8984/rest?query=db%3Aexport%28%27dbName%27%2C%22C%3A%5CUsers%5Cdak52%5CDocuments%5Cfolder%22%29&omit-xml-declaration=no
```

This runs and generates output, but this output does not include my xml declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Output Serialization Options

Generally, there are two options for declaring the output serialization parameters (I simplified the query):

- In the query prolog (`declare option output:omit-xml-declaration "no";`):

  http://localhost:8984/rest?query=declare%20option%20output:omit-xml-declaration%20%22no%22;%3Cfoo/%3E
- As a REST GET (or also POST) parameter as you have already tried:

  http://localhost:8984/rest?query=%3Cfoo/%3E&omit-xml-declaration=yes

### Export Serialization Options

The problem is these both set the *output serialization options*. You need to change the *export* options instead, as [described in the documentation](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Database_Module#db:export). For a query

```
db:export("foo", "/tmp", map { 'omit-xml-declaration': 'no' })
```

use the REST call

[http://localhost:8984/rest?query=db:export(%22foo%22,%20%22/tmp%22,%20map%20{%20%27omit-xml-declaration%27:%20%27no%27%20})](http://localhost:8984/rest?query=db:export(%22foo%22,%20%22/tmp%22,%20map%20%7B%20%27omit-xml-declaration%27:%20%27no%27%20%7D))

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and your edits to my original question. A quick followup: do you know if it is possible to have a line break inserted after the declaration so that the next element appears on the line below the xml declaration? If not, no worries. Thanks again @Jens Erat

Comment: I had a chat with the BaseX project lead today and this was [recorded as a minor bug](https://github.com/BaseXdb/basex/issues/1174). Follow the issue if you're interested in updates.